# Wordpress post loop - not working

Tags: wordpress

i am strugling with huge problem :( Whole day i am trying loop to work. I use default wordpress theme. if i put loop on index.php or home.php posts are working fine. And if i put loop in some pate templte for example blog-template.php i get blank screen ?? How loop work on index.php or archive.php or categories.php but not on any page templates???

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

As i said with this code on index.php i get graet results along with prev/next page buttons. But if i use on template file i got blank screen? 
Please help

Comment: Your problem is not related to your code. You get the blank page because of a syntax error. Enable debug by setting debug to true in wp-config.php.

Answer (score 4):

Place this preceding your loop. I suffered through the same issue.

`<?php query_posts('post_type=post') ?>`

EDIT:

That's a quick fix to the issue, I suppose. I just looked at the query_post function and the wordpress codex seems to violently denounce it; emphatically deriding it as inefficient and overly simplistic in usage. It does however recommend get_posts.

You aren't the only individual suffering this problem though. Wordpress, along with everyone else, seems to readily document using the loop but not really...implementing it.  I think most sites just sort've take it for granted you know what you're doing.

sigh.

Answer (score 2):

in page template you need to pass query_posts before have_posts

```
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',

);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: so in basic have code like this
  <?php 
   $args = array(
   'post_type'=> 'post',);
   query_posts( $args );
        ?>

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php /* The loop */ ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>
  <?php else : ?>
   <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

Comment: i tried but same result :( http://brezilla.info/drwerner/blog/  this is result i got

Comment: replace <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?> with <?php the_title(); ?> and let me know

Comment: my file was broklen so your firs tsolution works but not quite well. check please http://brezilla.info/drwerner/blog/  it show me posts and  older/new posts BUT as it seems it show same posts on both paegs? i limited from admin 2posts pare page, but when i click old it shows same posts ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40739/discussion-between-mitrovic-srdjan-and-bhumi-shah)

Comment: Pieter Goosen- then you post answer here

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps to create custom page template:

1. Create new file i.e. custom-page-template.php. Copy and paste the following commenting lines at the top of the file

   ```
   <?php
   /*

   Template Name: Custom Template 1

   */

   ?>
   ```
2. Copy and paste the following codes in custom-page-template.php:

   ```
   <?php 
   get_header(); 
   ?>

   <div id="primary" class="content-area">
       <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

       <?php /* The loop */ ?>
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

           <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
               <header class="entry-header">
                   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                   <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                   </div>
                   <?php endif; ?>

                   <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
               </header><!-- .entry-header -->

               <div class="entry-content">
                   <?php the_content(); ?>
                   <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
               </div><!-- .entry-content -->

               <footer class="entry-meta">
                   <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
               </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
           </article><!-- #post -->

           <?php comments_template(); ?>
       <?php endwhile; ?>

   </div><!-- #content -->
   ```
3. In the admin panel create new page and select the page template "Custom Template 1" from the page attribute panel (at right side). See the following image to select page template:

   [image]
4. Now save and see the view. It must work.

Comment: Hello i treid your approach also :)  i made new template , paste the code , created new page choose proper tempalte of course and -> http://brezilla.info/drwerner/new-page/    . i must mention i use fresh install of wordperss and fresh theme i did not alter functions.php or anything

Comment: did you put some content in the page? Because I saw title is shown so, content should be shown.

Comment: nope no content its empty page with title. i want to get those posts on blog page i did not belived that its so complicated :)
Solution of Bhumi Shah is working except older/newer posts buttons

Comment: http://brezilla.info/drwerner/new-page/  his solution show me the posts and links i wanted back/fwd but in address bar i see page1 page2 but same post loaded for every page

Comment: I thought, you wanted to create custom page template but actually you want to show some posts of category in a custom page template. I explained how to create custom page template. Now you can add your code to show posts. There are many ways: Bhumi shows one. You may read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts , http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts and http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Yes i wanna show all posts on that custom template page :) i tried many codes but there is always some problem like this pagintion dont work  http://brezilla.info/drwerner/blog/page/3/  and on index same stuff work http://brezilla.info/drwerner/page/3/   so what i am missing?

Comment: but in your question you mentioned, you are getting blank page. Please ask specifically then get solve fast.

Comment: With above solution of anotehr coder i got post working but now pagination dotn work it giving me same post for every page 1 2 3